# Device systematically disconnects when installing application with Android Studio

Tags: linux, usb, android, android-studio

## Problem

Every time I attempt to install and run an app from Android Studio to a physically plugged smartwatch (I develop wearable apps), the device gets disconnected from the ADB list of available devices before the application gets installed.

## Steps to reproduce

1. I unplug -> re-plug the desired device with a USB cable so it gets recognized by ADB and therefore listed in the menu of available devices in Android Studio.
2. I select the desired device from the list of connected devices in Android Studio.
3. I hit the 'Run' or 'Debug' button to install the app on the device.
4. After a few seconds, the device gets disconnected for no apparent reason, and Android Studio provides this message: [Android Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I9yU.png)

## Setup

- Android Studio 3.5.1
- Archlinux 5.3.5 (default kernel)

## Remarks

- The same problem occurs when using `adb` from the command line. Running the command `adb -s device-id install apk-name.apk` immediately disconnects the device.
- The dmesg command indicates that from a system point of view, the device is still connected and recognized.
- This problem occurs on any device I try. This is, therefore, not a cable or a device issue.
- The computer I work on also has a Windows partition. The problem does not occur under Windows. This seems to indicate that it is not a hardware issue. It might be a Linux issue or an Android Studio. I have no idea how to find out.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I have a similar situation  with my Mac. thanks

Answer (score 3):

One related problem in MAC(or may be other operating systems) can also be solved with this
You need disable "Use libusb backend" in preferences--> debugger

[image]

Please tell others if this was useful for you.
Thanks to the following user and their answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58095554/3726185

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, changed this and worked first time after restarting Android Studio. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest updating the Android Studio version.

I had the same issue in 3.5.1 and 3.5.2, but it's working for me in 3.6 Canary 11. Worth mentioning: When I updated to version 3.6, I didn't import the configuration from the previous version, but started from scratch instead.